# Old C code converting to R

Tags: c, r, rcpp

I've code for a statistical program that was originally coded in C circa 2008. I'm a novice user to R, and would like to convert this code into R. Is this an appropriate use of the Rcpp package?

Comment: *Where's your code?*.

Comment: I added a tag for Rcpp as this really is a 'can I do this with Rcpp' question.  You may want to edit your question though:  _"would like to call this code from R"_ is a more obvious way to state it.

Comment: if it's simple C code you may not even need to use Rcpp (although Rcpp would certainly make it shinier) -- you can probably just wrap it with a `.C()` call (see the R Extensions manual)

Comment: @BenBolker Use if `.C()` is actively discouraged; `.Call()` is much preferred and as the _interface_ is C anyway can call C or C++.  _Friends don't let friends use .C()._

Comment: Is it a main program with file I/O? Is it nicely written in modules? What do the subroutine headers look like? Does it link with a bunch of other libraries? This might get reopened if you add some specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is as C++ is (commonly, there are narrow and mostly irrelevant exceptions) a superset of C.

And Rcpp supports the atomistic C types you may have been using.  I'd still comment converting things like

```
  double *pvec, int nvec, ...
```

to describe a vector with the preferable

```
  std::vector<double> vec
```

or of course

```
  Rcpp::NumericVector vec
```

but you should have little difficulty.

Rcpp is not opionated and lets you use different C and C++ standards.  R itself has a preference for `-std=c99` though.